# Adding Item via button to specific Category in grouped data (C# MAUI)

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

so I was trying to add new Item to already existing Category, the new Item should go to the Category in which I clicked the button and I don't know how to do it.

these are my classes:

```
public class CategoryGroup : ObservableCollection<Item>
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public CategoryGroup(string name, ObservableCollection<Item> items) : base(items)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }

public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public ObservableCollection<CategoryGroup> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CategoryGroup>();
```

and I'm not sure how to tackle this problem

and I was trying to do something like this:

```
private async void AddNewItem(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        string categoryName = (string)button.CommandParameter;
        CategoryGroup category = Items.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == categoryName);
        if (category != null)
        {
            string name = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync(
                "Add Item", "Enter the name of the item");
            category.Add(new Item { Name = name, Quantity = 1, IsChecked = false, Id = "1" });
        //id set to 1 just for testing
        }
    }
```

with Button:

```
<ScrollView>
            <CollectionView IsGrouped="true" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                             FontSize="18"
                             FontAttributes="Bold"
                             Grid.Column="0"/>
                            //here
                            <Button Text="Add Item ➕" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="AddNewItem" CommandParameter="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemView:ItemView Name="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </ScrollView>
```

unfortunately, the button created in this way with this function does not even respond to the click

Comment: you need to bind the `CommandParameter`, not just use a hard coded string

Comment: @Jason you mean something like this? CommandParameter="{Binding CategoryName}. if yes, I just tried it and unfortunately the button is still not responding

Comment: yes, I would expect that to work

Comment: @Jason unfortunately not

Comment: you need to provide more info.  Is the event handler firing?  Is it getting the correct value from the `CommandParameter`?  Is the LINQ query working?

Comment: @Jason I can't answer most of these questions. I'm new to c# and maui (I'm doing this for a school project). All I know is that the button doesn't respond to clicking in any way. the debugger showed me that when I clicked: button.CommandParameter = null. so i guess there might be a problem here.

Comment: is the `Button` on the group or the individual `Item`?  And you need to learn how to use the VS debugger to step through your code.  There are many excellent tutorials available

Comment: @Jason I edited the question with the location of my button

Comment: `CategoryGroup` does not have a `CategoryName` property.

Comment: @Jason oh, a little embarrassing. thank you very much for your help and your time